# How to update the search title and page title depending on facet options

Tags: 7, search

I am using [Search Api Views](https://www.drupal.org/node/1597930) module to list some publications. User can filter them using facets. For example he can look for publications only in Kenya.

I want to update the title of my page (view) depending on this user selection.

Here is a screenshot of my application:

[image]

I tried to use [Facet API Bonus](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi_bonus) module, unfortunately I cannot figure out how to use it, I looked everywhere, but cannot find where the configuration interface is located..

Answer (score 0):

The solution is on the Facet API Bonus module's project page:

Integration with Page Title module Now you can set search (views) page titles using Page Title module. Module provides possibility to set tokens 'facetapi_results' and 'facetapi_active' groups. So in title we can display number of results on the page or values of active facets. As there can be multiple active facet values please use following pattern to use facetapi_active tokens:
list<[facetapi_active:facet-label]: [facetapi_active:active-value]>

This will make coma separated list of active facet labels and their values.